# CI builds fail after upgrade to TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I upgraded from TFS 2015 to 2017, and the continuous integration builds now fail with the error below. We host our own BitBucket server. I tried creating a new External Git service endpoint with the clone URL and the username and password, but it still fails with the same message. I did test that the username and password has access to the repositories. Manual builds succeed, but the CI builds that fail.

I suspect it has to do with the user used for the build. The CI builds say requested by Microsoft.TeamFoundation.System, while the builds that succeed say requested by [Development]\Project Collection Service Accounts.

Anyone else have this problem? Any suggestions?

```
An exception occurred while polling the repository. Error: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.ExternalConnectorException: Basic authentication requires a secure connection to the server. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Basic authentication requires a secure connection to the server.
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential.OnCreateTokenProvider(Uri serverUrl, IHttpResponse response)
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.IssuedTokenCredential.CreateTokenProvider(Uri serverUrl, IHttpResponse response, IssuedToken failedToken)
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssCredentials.TryGetTokenProvider(Uri serverUrl, IssuedTokenProvider& provider)
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitConnector.GetBranches(IVssRequestContext requestContext, ExternalConnection connection, Int32 timeoutSeconds)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitConnector.GetBranches(IVssRequestContext requestContext, ExternalConnection connection, Int32 timeoutSeconds)
 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitSourceProvider.GetMatchingBranchRefs(IVssRequestContext requestContext, BuildDefinition definition, IList`1 branchFilters)
 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.GitSourceProvider.GetSourceVersionsToBuild(IVssRequestContext requestContext, BuildDefinition definition, List`1 branchFilters, Boolean batchChanges, String previousVersionEvaluated, Dictionary`2& ciData, String& lastVersionEvaluated)
 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.Extensions.BuildPollingJobExtension.Run(IVssRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime queueTime, String& resultMessage).
```

Comment: Did you upgrade the build agent after you upgraded? TFS 2017 bumped the build agent version from 1.x to 2.x and requires a reinstallation.

Comment: I just finished upgrading the build agent. It's still throwing the same error. I have the agent running as a network service using the NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message seems to be telling you the precise problem:

> Basic authentication requires a secure connection to the server.

It seems like you're a username/password combination, but your BitBucket server isn't configured to use SSL. As a result, it's blocking access as the credentials would be transmitted plaintext, which isn't great from a security standpoint.

I believe BitBucket supports PAT authentication; you should be able to set that up by generating a PAT in BitBucket and replacing the username/password with the PAT.

Comment: Getting the SSL to work was tricky. TFS has a local copy of git for each build agent. I had to overwrite those copies with the server copy so they would have the same keystore.